# No Starting Hops - Do I need a 60 min boil?

Tags: hops, boil

I'm planning to brew a New England IPA where I only use knocked hops and dry hopping. Is there any point in boiling for an hour? What is the minimum time I should boil for? I'm thinking maybe 15 minutes.

Answer (score 4):

DMS is pretty much a non issue these days, so a short boil is fine.  I often do batches with a 20 min. mash and 20 min. boil  The beer turns out fine, with no hint of DMS.

Comment: What 2-row and Pils grain are you using? That makes this a non issue?

Comment: Pale malt- Mecca Grade, Great Western, Rahr  Pils - Best, Mecca Grade and Weyermann

Comment: insteresting, I've deffinatly had DMS with great western. BOS with a no pils Helles Bock, because it had iconic corny DMS. I guess as fast chills are easier this can reduce the need to long boils concerning DMS.

Comment: My experience is, and reading confirms it, that it's the vigor, not the length, of boil that's the factor.

Comment: vigor does help to expel and not condense and fall back in contrast to a simmering boil. However DMS has a Half-Life of 38 minutes at water boiling point. Time is a definite factor in removing it.

Comment: is it possible that the reference material you're using is dated and doesn't take into account current malting process and barley varieties?

Comment: possible. I'm not aware of any malting process to reduce DMS in light grains.

Comment: Old article on malting practices and DMS production: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/j.2050-0416.1977.tb03799.x

Answer (score 3):

Certainly. The guys from [Brülosophy](http://brulosophy.com/) do this with their "Short and Shoddy" series.

Make sure that you hit your OG almost before the boil, because you will not have much evaporation.

Comment: This is a confusing answer... Certainly you can have a short boil or certainly you need a full boil?

Answer (score 2):

Boils are 60-90 minutes not for hops but to boil off DMS, in all grain brewing.

If you're doing extract brewing then yes a short boil is ok. DMS has been taken care of in the extract production process.

Answer (score 0):

If one is doing extract brewing then it is not *necessary* to boil the malt at all. I have made very good beers using malt extract dissolved in hot water and dry hopping the resulting wort in the FV.

If using all grain then boiling can be useful to denature the amylase enzymes (etc) and to pasteurise the wort but that can be done in 5 minutes (or less).